# Does the electron confinement energy vary with temperature?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I was introduced the [electron confinement energy](https://www.google.com/search?q=electron+confinement+energy). At room temperature thermal energy of a particle is about $k_B T$, where $T=298K$, giving about $25meV$. I was told that $E_\text{confinement}=50emV$, ~$2k_B T$. Does $E_\text{confinement}\approx2k_B T$ hold for all temperatures?
Does $E_\text{confinement}$ vary with temperature?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about a confinement energy as e.g. [used here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html), no, it is not always of order $k_b T$, since the only input into the "confinement calculation" is the uncertaintly principle for $x,p$ and $\Delta x$ of order of the atom radius.

Consequently, since $E\text{confinement}\propto (\Delta p)^2 \propto (\Delta x)^{-2}$, the variation of the confinement energy depends on the variation of the atom radius with temperature, which I believe to be neglegible in most cases, and not analytically known, anyway.